# Shadow of incomplete triangle

Tags: three.js

Good afternoon!
I'm starting studies with THREE JS.
I hope I'm not doing anything wrong.
But come on, the question is this.
I created a custom geometry.
Adding vertices and then adding faces to the geometry.
And then a triangle with two faces was created.
But when I put a light with SpotLight, the shadow of the triangle gets incomplete.
Someone please explain this to me?

printScreen -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxXbz.jpg

```
    var trianguloGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,50,0));
    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50,0,0));

    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,50,0));
    trianguloGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50,0,0));


    trianguloGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
    trianguloGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3,4,5));

    trianguloGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
    trianguloGeometry.computeFlatVertexNormals ();

var triangulo = new THREE.Mesh(
        trianguloGeometry,
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color:'red',
            side:THREE.DoubleSide,
            vertexColors:THREE.FaceColors
        }),
    );

    scene.add(triangulo);

    triangulo.castShadow = true;
```

Comment: Please add the code, and then people can help.

Comment: Read about [SpotLightShadow](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/shadows/SpotLightShadow).

Comment: Well, thanks for the answers.
But I solved, updating three.js for the r90 revision, hence I was able to use shadowSide: THREE.DoubleSide

Thank you